# VueJS - sometimes getting error "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'process' of undefined"

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I am working on a project with Vue.JS and Laravel 5.2.

It is a program to train vocabulary. So there is an array in my Vue-Data-Object, containing wordpairs. Each wordpair is stored as an object:

```
"words": [
    {
      "lang1": "Haus",
      "lang2": "house",
      "lang1_hint": "",
      "lang2_hint": "",
      "image_url": "",
      "tries": 0,
      "fails": 0,
      "process": 1
    },
    {
      "lang1": "Feuer",
      "lang2": "fire",
      "lang1_hint": "",
      "lang2_hint": "",
      "image_url": "",
      "tries": 0,
      "fails": 0,
      "process": 5
    },
    ...
]
```

Now i have a function, which takes the length of the array, generates a random number and returns a random number out of the array above:

```
getRandomWord: function(){
    var i = Math.floor((Math.random() * this.words.length) + 1);
    if(this.words[i].process == 5){
        return this.getRandomWord();
    } else {
        return {
            index: i,
            content: this.words[i]
        }
    }
}
```

Mostly there is no problem. But sometimes, there occurs an error saying:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'process' of undefined
```

The console says, that the error occurs in the if-condition of my getRandomWord() `if(this.words[i].process == 5)`.

Any idea why? The value of process is always 1, 2, 3, 4 or 5.

Thanks so far!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first index of a Javascript array is 0, so the last index of your array is `array.length - 1`. Your code for generating the index:

```
  Math.floor((Math.random() * this.words.length) + 1);
```

will sometimes generate an index of `length` - which does not exist. Remove the `+1` and you should be good.

Comment: Oh man... thanks! I know that an array begins at 0 but this was not the direction I was looking for a solutions.

Answer (score 1):

Im pretty sure that you have problem in here

```
  var i = Math.floor((Math.random() * this.words.length) + 1);
```

Remove +1 and you should be good to go.Remember arrays starts with index 0

Answer (score 1):

The error means that `this.words[i]` is undefined for some `i`.

You should write

```
var i = Math.floor((Math.random() * this.words.length));
```